# Passing vector of objects to new dialog window (Qt C++)

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I've got very strange problem.

I've created class which contains few string and ints:

```c#
class muzyka
{
    string artist;
    string album;
    string genre;
    string type;
    string label;
    string cat_nr;
    int songs;
    int year;

public:

    muzyka();
    muzyka(string ar, string al, string g, string t, string l, string c, int s, int y);
    ~muzyka();

    void setartist(string ar);
    void setalbum(string al);
    void setgenre(string g);
    void settype(string t);
    void setlabel(string l);
    void setcat_nr(string c);
    void setsongs(int s);
    void setyear(int y);

    void setall(string ar, string al, string g, string t, string l, string c, int s, int y);

    string getartist();
    string getalbum();
    string getgenre();
    string gettype();
    string getlabel();
    string getcat_nr();
    int getsongs();
    int getyear();

};
```

I created a vector for storing this objects. My problem is that I have 2 classes (MainWindow and Dialog). In MainWindow I have QTableWidget which shows all records. New records are adding in Dialog window which contains line edit boxes.

This vector is created as a global variable in mainwindow.cpp (I know it's a bad habit)
I created functions as a public methods in mainwindow and dialog classes to send and recieve my vector. It looks like this:

Dialog(recieves old vector, which was displayed on QTable

```c#
void add::recieve(QVector<muzyka> &db)
{
    cont = db;

}
```

MainWindow(recieves edited vector)

```
void MainWindow::pass(QVector<muzyka> cont)
{
    db = cont;

}
```

part of dialog window.cpp looks like this:

```
cont.push_back(muzyka(ar, al, g, t, l, c, s, y));

MainWindow a;

a.pass(cont);
```

And in mainwindow.cpp I have refresh button:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(db.size());
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(8);


   QVector<muzyka>::iterator i;

   for(i = db.begin(); i != db.end(); ++i)
   {
     for(int row = 0; row < db.size(); row++)
    {
         QString temp_1,temp_2,temp_3,temp_4,temp_5,temp_6;
         int temp1,temp2;

         temp_1=(*i).getartist().c_str();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,0,new QTableWidgetItem(temp_1));

         temp_2=(*i).getalbum().c_str();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,1,new QTableWidgetItem(temp_2));

         temp1=(*i).getsongs();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,2,new QTableWidgetItem(temp1));

         temp2=(*i).getyear();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,3,new QTableWidgetItem(temp2));

         temp_3=(*i).getgenre().c_str();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,4,new QTableWidgetItem(temp_3));

         temp_4=(*i).getlabel().c_str();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,5,new QTableWidgetItem(temp_4));

         temp_5=(*i).gettype().c_str();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,6,new QTableWidgetItem(temp_5));

         temp_6=(*i).getcat_nr().c_str();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,7,new QTableWidgetItem(temp_6));

     }

}
```

When I add first record and press refresh button in QTable I see my data(not exacly quite good but it's not problem for now). But when I try to add next record after refreshing I see two rows of the second object.
I have really no idea what's wrong. I guess it may be something with passing vector to windows.

Do you have any solution for this?

I will be really thankful for any help.

Comment: Ok, I found out what's going on. I messed up loops at refresh button.
I changed 'for(int row = 0; row < db.size(); row++)' for 'if(row!=db.size()); row++;' and now is working.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to remove your first loop, then use db.at(row) instead (*i).